# getting panic() argument in defer function in GO lang

Tags: go

I have a function A calling function B which would sometime call panic based on invalid data.
In function A defer function, I would like to know the message function B passed to the panic() so that I can report the error in json over the network back to the client.

e.g.

```
func A( abc data) result string{
  defer func(){
    // get panic args and return result.
  }

  xx = B( abc[0] );
  yy = B( abc[1] );
  ...
}
```

The reason function B use panic is to avoid a very large amount of

```
err := B(abc)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
```

in function A and make the code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
package main

import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
)

func A(s string) (result string, err error) {
        defer func() {
                if e := recover(); e != nil {
                        switch x := e.(type) {
                        case error:
                                err = x
                        default:
                                err = fmt.Errorf("%v", x)
                        }
                }
        }()

        B(s)
        return "returned", nil
}

func B(s string) {
        switch s {
        case "ok":
                return
        case "fail":
                panic(errors.New("failed"))
        case "fail miserably":
                panic(42)
        default:
                a, b := 1, 0
                if a/b != 0 {
                        panic("ouch")
                }
        }
}

func main() {
        s, err := A("ok")
        fmt.Printf("%q, %T(%#v)\n", s, err, err)

        s, err = A("fail")
        fmt.Printf("%q, %T(%#v)\n", s, err, err)

        s, err = A("fail miserably")
        fmt.Printf("%q, %T(%#v)\n", s, err, err)

        s, err = A("")
        fmt.Printf("%q, %T(%#v)\n", s, err, err)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zV-nW_1iMf)

---

Output:

```
"returned", <nil>(<nil>)
"", *errors.errorString(&errors.errorString{s:"failed"})
"", *errors.errorString(&errors.errorString{s:"42"})
"", runtime.errorString("integer divide by zero")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `recover` function. You're right to want to defer it - recover only works properly in a deferred function (if you call it in the body, it will either return nil if there was no panic, or get skipped over when a panic does happen). Recover returns the value that was panicked in an empty interface:

```
func A(abc data) result string {
    defer func() {
        p := recover() // p is an interface{} value, and will be nil if there was no panic
    }() // You have to call the function
    ...
}
```