# Setting variables in defer on recovery

Tags: go

Per examples (e.g. [getting panic() argument in defer function in GO lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255665/getting-panic-argument-in-defer-function-in-go-lang)) I've seen, I'm expecting this to work, but it isn't. When forcing an error, the `err` return string remains blank, although printing the err string shows the expected error.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't find it. A little help?

```
// expected error example:
// chk, err := equal("a", map[string]string{"a"})
//
func Equal(a interface{}, b interface{}) (check bool, err string) {
    defer func() {
        if catch := recover(); catch != nil {
            check = false

            // this prints
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", catch)

            err = fmt.Sprint(catch)
        }
    }()

    return a == b, ""
}
```

BTW:

```
go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64
```

Comment: There's no panic() in that code, so recover() should return nil. http://play.golang.org/p/sXaAiRjvJb does what's expected, do you have a complete example ?

Comment: I just realized that. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nos pointed out, there's no panic, here.

This example works as expected:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func equal(a interface{}, b interface{}) (check bool, err string) {
    defer func() {
        if catch := recover(); catch != nil {
            check = false
            fmt.Printf("recover: %v\n", catch)
            err = fmt.Sprint(catch)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("recover: none\n")
        }
    }()

    return a == b, ""
}

func main() {
    chk, err := equal("a", "a")
    fmt.Printf("a == a\n")
    fmt.Printf("chk: %v\n", chk)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    fmt.Println()

    chk, err = equal("a", 1)
    fmt.Printf("a == 1\n")
    fmt.Printf("chk: %v\n", chk)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    fmt.Println()

    chk, err = equal([]int{1}, []int{1})
    fmt.Printf("[]int{1}, []int{1}\n")
    fmt.Printf("chk: %v\n", chk)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
}

// Output:
//
// recover: none
// a == a
// chk: true
// err:
// recover: none
//
// a == 1
// chk: false
// err:
// recover: runtime error: comparing uncomparable type []int
//
// []int{1}, []int{1}
// chk: false
// err: runtime error: comparing uncomparable type []int
```